# Entity Framework: Entity to include a fixed number of navigational property : how to write this query

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

I am having 2 entities as described below

```
public class Product 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }    
}

public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }    

    [ForeignKey("Product")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product  Product { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to write a query which includes only 10 comments for a particular  product. The query i have written below includes all comments on product.

```
var product = db.Products.Include(a=>a.Comments).Take(10);
```

Please suggest is it possible in entity framework.

### Edit 1

changed this query to

```
var product = db.Products.Include(a=>a.Comments).FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Id==1);
```

this one

```
var product = db.Products.Include(a=>a.Comments).Take(10);
```

---

**I have to load 10 products with 10 comments each.**

Answer (score 1):

This will work if you don't mind returning an anonymous type or a poco:

```
var products = from x in db.Products.Take(10)
              select new 
              {
                ProductProperty1 = x.Property1,
                Comments = x.Comments.Take(10),
              };

var product = products.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.ProductProperty1 ==1);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can always reverse that and get the `Comments` with the product:

```
var comments = db.Comments.Include(c => c.Product)
    .Where(c => c.Product.Id == 1)
    .Take(10);
```

Comment: i have edited the question as- I have to load 10 products with 10 comments each.

Comment: true, however there is no information in the question that suggest either

Comment: @RusiNova you mean any 10 products which have exactly 10 comments?

Comment: @vitaliy yes: get_first_10_prodducts_with_ten_comments_on_each_product

Answer (score 0):

I believe that following will do:

```
var comments = db.Comments.Where(c=>c.ProductId==1).Take(10).ToList();
var product = db.Products.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Id==1);
```